# Sequelize: Object does not return after creation. No errors. Object present in DB

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

Object is created in the DB, but not returned.  No errors.

`User` is the only `table` this happens to.  Logging is on.

`User` model:

```
module.exports = function (sequelize, DataTypes) {
    var User = sequelize.define("User", {
        email: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowedNull: false,
            unique: true,
            validate: {
                isEmail: true
            }
        },
        username: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowedNull: true,
            unique: true,
            validate: {
                len: [4, 50]
            }
        },
        first_name: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowedNull: true,
            validate: {
                len: [2, 50]
            }
        },
        last_name: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowedNull: true,
            validate: {
                len: [2, 50]
            }
        },         
    }, {
            tableName: 'User',
            charset: 'utf8mb4',
            collate: 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            ........
```

No `afterCreate` Hooks in the `User` model.

When I call the code below, a `User` Object is created, however, it doesn't return:

```
 db.User.create({email: body.email}).then((userCreated) => {
                   // userCreated Object is never returned, but an Object in the DB is created.  
                    console.log("User Created " + userCreated)
                }).catch((errorCreatingUser) => {
                // No Error is returned either
                    console.log("user error " + errorCreatingUser)
                })
                console.log("Outside of the block ")
```

Below is the log:

```
Executing (default): SELECT `id`, `email`, `username`, `first_name`, `last_name`, `createdAt`, `updatedAt` FROM `User` AS `User` WHERE `User`.`email` = 'example@example.com' LIMIT 1;
sequelize.js:1344
Outside of the block 
controller.js:478
Executing (default): INSERT INTO `User` (`id`,`email`,`createdAt`,`updatedAt`) VALUES (DEFAULT,'example@example.com','2019-09-02 16:01:29','2019-09-02 16:01:29');
```

Any ideas what I am doing wrong or troubleshooting suggestions?

**UPDATED WITH ENTIRE FLOW CODE**

```
router.post('/login', (req, res) => {
    var _ = req.app.get('_')
    var body = _.pick(req.body, 'username', 'email');
    var db = req.app.get('db');


    db.User.create({email: body.email}).then((userCreated) => {
        console.log("User Created " + userCreated)
    }).catch((errorCreatingUser) => {
        console.log("user error " + errorCreatingUser)
    })
    console.log("Out of the block ")
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not clear about the promise OR async flow of node, **here in code I have commented the number in sequence how it will execute**

**4 will be executed when there is no more process left in synchronous mode.**

```
console.log("Before Create");   //<------------- 1
return db.User.create({ email: body.email}) //<------------- 2
.then((userCreated) => { //<------------- 4 ( if scuccess )
  // userCreated Object is never returned, but an Object in the DB is created.  
  console.log("User Created " + userCreated) 
}).catch((errorCreatingUser) => { //<------------- 4 ( if failed )
  // No Error is returned either
  console.log("user error " + errorCreatingUser)
})
console.log("Outside of the block "); //<------------- 3
```

---

Try to run below code :

```
router.post('/login', (req, res) => {
    var _ = req.app.get('_')
    var body = _.pick(req.body, 'username', 'email');
    var db = req.app.get('db');


    return db.User.create({email: body.email}).then((userCreated) => { // <--------- Add return
        console.log("User Created " + userCreated);
        return userCreated; // <--------- Add return
    }).catch((errorCreatingUser) => { 
        console.log("user error " + errorCreatingUser)
    })
    console.log("Out of the block ")
})
```

Comment: @user1107173, it does always you might be returning before execution or might be other issue

Comment: There's no return after `console.log("Outside of the block ");`

Comment: @user1107173, check updated answer and try that out

Comment: Thank you.  I tried your code.  Below is the log:
`POST /login
app.js:32
Executing (default): INSERT INTO `User` (`id`,`email`,`createdAt`,`updatedAt`) VALUES (DEFAULT,'uniqueEmail@example.com','2019-09-02 19:54:47','2019-09-02 19:54:47');`

Answer (score 0):

try using async await because it is easy to understand the flow with them.

```
router.post('/login', async (req, res) => {
  try{
    var _ = req.app.get('_')
    var body = _.pick(req.body, 'username', 'email');
    var db = req.app.get('db');
    var newUser =  await db.User.create({ email: body.email });
    console.log("User created " + newUser);
    console.log("Out of the block ")
  }catch(error){
    console.log("user creation error .. " + error);
  }
})
```